# Is it correct to say "Exciting movies are hard to find"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Is the following sentence correct?

> Exciting movies are hard to find.

I know people usually say that it is hard to find exciting movies.   But I have to make a sentence that starts with exciting movies are adjective to infinitives. Is the given sentence correct? Could you help me clarify it?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly OK to reverse the order like this. Here is an example that is used as a title for a book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Good_Man_Is_Hard_to_Find_(short_story)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds great.  The sentence you have composed is perfect and you are doing an admirable job.

> "Exciting movies are hard to find."

Keep up the good work!